# R - How to change elements in a matrix starting from a specific point

Tags: r

I have a data frame M, which looks like:

```
 [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]     [,5]
 [1,] 0.4212778 0.6874073 0.1551896 Cluster_1
 [2,] 0.6874073 0.5610995 0.1779030 Cluster_1
 [3,] 0.1551896 0.1779030 0.9515304 Cluster_1
 [4,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_1_A
 [5,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_1
 [6,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_1
 [7,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2
 [8,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_A
 [9,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2
[10,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2
[11,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_1_A
[12,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2
[13,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2
[14,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_3
[15,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_3
[15,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_3
[16,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_4
[17,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_4
```

I want to assign the same name of the elements of the matrix (column 5) in the range starting from the element with "_A" flag until the next name change.
In this case:

- from M[4,5] until element M[6,5]
- from M[8,5] until element M[10,5]
- from M[11,5] until element M[13,5]

The result I want is the following:

```
 [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]     [,5]
 [1,] 0.4212778 0.6874073 0.1551896 Cluster_1
 [2,] 0.6874073 0.5610995 0.1779030 Cluster_1
 [3,] 0.1551896 0.1779030 0.9515304 Cluster_1
 [4,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_1_A
 [5,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_1_A
 [6,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_1_A
 [7,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2
 [8,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_A
 [9,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_A
[10,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_A
[11,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_1_A
[12,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_1_A
[13,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_1_A
[14,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_3
[15,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_3
[15,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_3
[16,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_4
[17,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_4
```

How can I do that quickly, also avoiding a for loop (which I'm able to code)? I've seen many similar posts, but no one gave me what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, convert your (what looks like a matrix) into a data.frame:

```
df = structure(list(value1 = c(0.4212778, 0.6874073, 0.1551896, 0.4675764, 
0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 
0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 
0.4675764, 0.4675764), value2 = c(0.6874073, 0.5610995, 0.177903, 
0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 
0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 
0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295), value3 = c(0.1551896, 0.177903, 
0.9515304, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 
0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 
0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978), cluster = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L), .Label = c("Cluster_1", "Cluster_1_A", "Cluster_2", "Cluster_2_1_A", 
"Cluster_2_A", "Cluster_3", "Cluster_4"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

head(df)

     value1    value2    value3     cluster
1 0.4212778 0.6874073 0.1551896   Cluster_1
2 0.6874073 0.5610995 0.1779030   Cluster_1
3 0.1551896 0.1779030 0.9515304   Cluster_1
4 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_1_A
5 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_1
6 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_1
```

If we do the following:

```
df$id = as.numeric(factor(df$cluster))

head(df,10)
      value1    value2    value3     cluster id
1  0.4212778 0.6874073 0.1551896   Cluster_1  1
2  0.6874073 0.5610995 0.1779030   Cluster_1  1
3  0.1551896 0.1779030 0.9515304   Cluster_1  1
4  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_1_A  2
5  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_1  1
6  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_1  1
7  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_2  3
8  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_A  5
9  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_2  3
10 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_2  3
```

You can see everytime there is an increase i.e from 1 to 2 at row 3:4 or 3 to 5 at row 7:8, it's where we want to separate them. So we do this:

```
df$grp = cumsum(c(0,diff(df$id)>0))

      value1    value2    value3     cluster id grp
1  0.4212778 0.6874073 0.1551896   Cluster_1  1   0
2  0.6874073 0.5610995 0.1779030   Cluster_1  1   0
3  0.1551896 0.1779030 0.9515304   Cluster_1  1   0
4  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_1_A  2   1
5  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_1  1   1
6  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_1  1   1
7  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_2  3   2
8  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_A  5   3
9  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_2  3   3
```

Your new id is simply:

```
df$new = unlist(
tapply(as.character(df$cluster),
df$grp,
function(i)rep(i[1],length(i))))

      value1    value2    value3       cluster id grp           new
1  0.4212778 0.6874073 0.1551896     Cluster_1  1   0     Cluster_1
2  0.6874073 0.5610995 0.1779030     Cluster_1  1   0     Cluster_1
3  0.1551896 0.1779030 0.9515304     Cluster_1  1   0     Cluster_1
4  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_1_A  2   1   Cluster_1_A
5  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_1  1   1   Cluster_1_A
6  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_1  1   1   Cluster_1_A
7  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_2  3   2     Cluster_2
8  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_2_A  5   3   Cluster_2_A
9  0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_2  3   3   Cluster_2_A
10 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_2  3   3   Cluster_2_A
11 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_1_A  4   4 Cluster_2_1_A
12 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_2  3   4 Cluster_2_1_A
13 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_2  3   4 Cluster_2_1_A
14 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_3  6   5     Cluster_3
15 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_3  6   5     Cluster_3
16 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_3  6   5     Cluster_3
17 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_4  7   6     Cluster_4
18 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_4  7   6     Cluster_4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I got it :)

Comment: nice solution, liked it! Mine is a bit tough for understanding when compared to yours :)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thank you :) it's a very similar, basically split it up and then if there is a jutting _A replace it..

Answer (score 1):

You can try the base R solution below, which applied `ave` + `gsub`

```
M <- within(M,V5 <- ave(V5,
                          gsub("(Cluster_\\d+).*","\\1",V5), 
                          FUN = function(x) ave(x,
                                                cumsum(grepl("_A",x)),
                                                FUN = function(q) head(q,1))))
```

such that

```
> M
      V1        V2        V3        V4            V5
1   [1,] 0.4212778 0.6874073 0.1551896     Cluster_1
2   [2,] 0.6874073 0.5610995 0.1779030     Cluster_1
3   [3,] 0.1551896 0.1779030 0.9515304     Cluster_1
4   [4,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_1_A
5   [5,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_1_A
6   [6,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_1_A
7   [7,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_2
8   [8,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_2_A
9   [9,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_2_A
10 [10,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978   Cluster_2_A
11 [11,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_1_A
12 [12,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_1_A
13 [13,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978 Cluster_2_1_A
14 [14,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_3
15 [15,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_3
16 [15,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_3
17 [16,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_4
18 [17,] 0.4675764 0.5407295 0.7942978     Cluster_4
```

**DATA**

```
M <- structure(list(V1 = c("[1,]", "[2,]", "[3,]", "[4,]", "[5,]", 
"[6,]", "[7,]", "[8,]", "[9,]", "[10,]", "[11,]", "[12,]", "[13,]", 
"[14,]", "[15,]", "[15,]", "[16,]", "[17,]"), V2 = c(0.4212778, 
0.6874073, 0.1551896, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 
0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 
0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764, 0.4675764), V3 = c(0.6874073, 
0.5610995, 0.177903, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 
0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 
0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295, 0.5407295), V4 = c(0.1551896, 
0.177903, 0.9515304, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 
0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 
0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978, 0.7942978), V5 = c("Cluster_1", 
"Cluster_1", "Cluster_1", "Cluster_1_A", "Cluster_1", "Cluster_1", 
"Cluster_2", "Cluster_2_A", "Cluster_2", "Cluster_2", "Cluster_2_1_A", 
"Cluster_2", "Cluster_2", "Cluster_3", "Cluster_3", "Cluster_3", 
"Cluster_4", "Cluster_4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```